# Why is Circular reference in struct of instance type not allowed but circular reference of static type allowed?

Tags: c#

why can we have a static circular reference in struct but not a instance type circular reference ?

```
struct C
{
    //following line is not allowed. Compile time error.
    // it's a non static circular reference.
    public C c1;
    //But this line compiles fine.
    //static circular reference.
    public static C c2;
}
```

Comment: If you have field of struct in itself then you can't determine the size of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The non-static reference fails because you're trying to make the structure a part of itself, which results in the circular reference.

The static declaration works because `c2` is not a part of the structure itself; whenever you declare e.g. `C foo`, `c2` does not affect the size of `foo`.